# Double double quotes in the string

Tags: c#, quotes

In c#: I need to create oracle query string like this:

```
string orQr = @"
    SELECT ""Date"", ""Key""
    FROM TBL
";
```

I need to do it dynamicly. But there is a problem with escaping double-double quotes.

How to do that? This is a little mad ;-) and doesn't work:

```
string quotes = @"""""";
string subSlct = quotes + "Date" + quotes + ", " + quotes + "Key" + quotes;
string orQrB = @"
    SELECT " + subSlct + @"
    FROM TBL
";
```

(the result is: SELECT \"\"Date\"\", \"\"Key\"\"\ FROM TBL )

Comment: if you really want to concatenate strings like this try using [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of messy unreadable `+`

Comment: Unless the names contain special characters, you do not need to enquote them, e.g. `"SELECT Date, Key FROM TBL"` should work fine.

Comment: Also look into [SqlCommandBuilder.QuoteIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.quoteidentifier.aspx).

Comment: poke: Yes, it could be true, but, in real, I need to create oracle dynamic pivot query and the year-week values are in the column-headers (like 201429), so I need to write "201429"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `quotes` variable is adding *two* double quotes, instead of one. Change this:

```
string quotes = @"""""";
```

to this:

```
string quotes = @"""";
```

Also:

1. There's nothing wrong with `string.Format("SELECT \"{0}\", \"{1}\" FROM TBL", a, b);`
2. Your code is susceptible to [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/).

   In general, you'd want to use parameterized queries, but since these don't allow parameterized column names, you'll want to at the very least sanitize the input yourself and check for illegal characters (e.g., `;`, `--`).

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
string quotes = "\"\"";
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't construct your query by string concatenation. You open yourself to SQL injection attacks. Use **parameterized queries** and you will also be able to include the quotes more easily.

Comment: Parameters don’t apply to names though, e.g. column names as in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use normal escaping like: `string quotes = "\"\"";`